# Sum values of two columns and display in next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, window-functions

I have a table which looks as below:

```
select * from #tempTable

    RN  Qty
    0   30
    1   -3
    2   -2
    3   8
```

Using the below query I was able to do as below:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY RN) AS RN, Qty
FROM #tempTable)

SELECT T1.RN,T1.Qty StartingQty,T2.Qty as ChangedQty, (T1.Qty+T2.Qty) as TotalQty
FROM CTE T1 LEFT JOIN
     CTE T2 ON T1.RN=(T2.RN-1) where T2.Qty IS not null
```

This would result as below:

```
    RN  StartingQty ChangedQty  TotalQty
    1    30            -3         27
    2    -3            -2         -5
    3    -2             8          6
```

The result should look as below and not sure how to achieve this:

```
    RN  StartingQty ChangedQty  TotalQty
    1    30            -3         27
    2    27            -2         25
    3    25             8         33
```

Any leads would be helpful as of how to achieve this.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: Management Studio 2018, verion 2016

Comment: As i said above 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You may try an approach using `LEAD()` and windowed `SUM()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT
      RN,
      SUM(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY RN) AS StartingQty,
      LEAD(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY RN) AS ChangedQty,
      SUM(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY RN) + LEAD(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY RN) AS TotalQty
   FROM (VALUES
      (0, 30),
      (1, -3),
      (2, -2),
      (3, 8)
   ) v (RN, Qty)
) t
WHERE ChangedQty IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
RN  StartingQty ChangedQty  TotalQty
0            30         -3        27
1            27         -2        25
2            25          8        33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the basic values using window functions and window frames:

```
select rn, qty as StartingQty,
       lead(qty) over (order by rn) as ChangedQty,
       sum(qty) over (order by rn rows between unbounded preceding and 1 following) as TotalQty
from (values (0, 30),
             (1, -3),
             (2, -2),
             (3, 8)
     ) v (rn, Qty);
```

To eliminate the last row, alas, you need a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select rn, qty as StartingQty,
             lead(qty) over (order by rn) as ChangedQty,
             sum(qty) over (order by rn rows between unbounded preceding and 1 following) as TotalQty
      from (values (0, 30),
                   (1, -3),
                   (2, -2),
                   (3, 8)
           ) v (rn, Qty)
     ) t
where changedqty is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b0ee5dcd37b7f0cc60b0f5763a3b060c) is a db<>fiddle.